# React route for sidebar switches URL but doesn't change actual view

Tags: reactjs, routes, components, react-router-dom

This is my `app.js` file. Everything seems to be fine here, I don't believe anything needs changing here as the routes work perfect when I simply type in the url.

```
import React, { Component }from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// Layouts
import Header from '../components/layouts/Header';
import Sidebar from '../components/layouts/Sidebar';

// Views
import Repos from '../components/views/Repos';
import Events from '../components/views/Events';
import Hooks from '../components/views/Hooks';
import Issues from '../components/views/Issues';
import Members from '../components/views/Members';
import PublicMembers from '../components/views/PublicMembers';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Sidebar /> 
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Repos}/>
            <Route exact path='/repos' component={Repos}/>
            <Route path='/events' component={Events}/>
            <Route path='/hooks' component={Hooks}/>
            <Route exact path='/issues' component={Issues}/>
            <Route path='/members' component={Members}/>
            <Route path='/public_members' component={PublicMembers}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById('root')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

This is my sidebar. On this I get I url change but I don't see the new view. Is it possible I need to pass something more down to this view? Or am I not writing out the correct call?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Sidebar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <List disablePadding dense style={styleSidebar}>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}><Link to="/repos">Repos</Link></ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}><Link to="/events">Events</Link></ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}><Link to="/hooks">Hooks</Link></ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}><Link to="/issues">Issues</Link></ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}><Link to="/members">Members</Link></ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}><Link to="/public_members">Public Members</Link></ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}  

export default Sidebar
```

Comment: Remove the enclosing `<Router>` parent component from `Sidebar` component. Hope It works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Your `SideBar` is being rendered inside another `Router`. The `Link` components use the router context from the closest `Router`. Or in other words, the `Router` context being used in `App` isn't being updated because the nested router handled it.

## Solution

Remove the `Router` wrapping the sidebar.

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <List disablePadding dense style={styleSidebar}>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>
            <Link to="/repos">Repos</Link>
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>
            <Link to="/events">Events</Link>
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>
            <Link to="/hooks">Hooks</Link>
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>
            <Link to="/issues">Issues</Link>
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>
            <Link to="/members">Members</Link>
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>
            <Link to="/public_members">Public Members</Link>
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```